# Routing the packets using mac address in policy routing for two NIC device

Tags: macos, routes, ip, nic

I am using policy based routing in my PC having two NICs.This is the content of script which i use to run at startup to configure the routing.
My two NIC's IPs are 192.168.1.123/24 and 192.168.1.124/24

echo "1 first">> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 table first

ip rule add from 192.168.1.124/32 table first

ip rule add to 192.168.1.124/32 table first

But this is some kind of hardcoding. That is if i change the IP of 1.123/24 to some other, then its working with the new IP. But if i change the IP of 1.124/24 then i will have to add the rules once again for the new IP address.

Is there some way to set rules based on the MAC address rather than device IP address?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can not do routing on the MAC address base. Routing works on L3 of ISO/OSI model. MAC addresses are on L2.